# Converting a timestamp value to number

Tags: oracle, datetime, type-conversion

I've a timestamp value in the format `2005-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00`. I want covert it to a number in the format`20050131`, to equate it to a column which has the datatype of number.

I tried to do it by `to_number(to_date(timestamp, 'yyyymmdd'))`. But it is resulting in error `not a valid month`.

Could you please help me in resolving it.

Comment: First convert it to a string

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen
`select to_number(to_date(cast('2005-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00' as VARCHAR2(30)), 'yyyymmdd'))
from dual`

I did as mentioned, but still getting the same `not a valid month`

Comment: Can you tell me what is this date time 2005-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00 format ? Ex. 2005-01-31 as YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: there aren't any rules, I wanted it in the number format, to equate it to another column

Answer (score 0):

try using like below

```
to_number(to_char(timestamp, 'yyyymmdd'))
```

first you have to convert to char and then to number.

Comment: when I did as you mentioned, I'm getting the error `not a valid number`
@Exhausted

Comment: does the to_char gives value.

Comment: check the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/71947/274 which works fine with systimestamp.

Comment: I think there is a error in your timestamp format. tell whether its a varchar or timestamp in table

Comment: its a `timestamp`, not a `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

If your timestamp value is a `VARCHAR2` value, maybe this will help:

```
WITH tstmp AS (
  SELECT '2005-01-31T00:00:00.000-05:00' AS val FROM dual
)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(val, 1, 23), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3'), SUBSTR(val, 24)) , 'YYYYMMDD')) AS newval
  FROM tstmp;
```

Comment: it's not `VARCHAR2`. its a `timestamp`